# Service workers implementation within Angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, service-worker

given the fact that as of today (december 2016) `--mobile` flag has been temporarily removed from Angular-cli ([Github statement](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#support-for-offline-applications)), how would you implement service-workers within an Angular app? Thank you in advance

EDIT: Here's a fresh a talk from #IO17 dealing with PWAs and Angular: [Stephen fluid's talk on PWAs and Angular, Google IO 17](https://youtu.be/C8KcW1Nj3Mw?t=10m59s)

Answer (score 2):

You can use plugins like `serviceworker-webpack-plugin`: https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin

You can also find a great tutorial here: https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers

I would recommend reading the tutorial first as it shows you that you don't necessarily need extra plugins in order to use service workers in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Add `"serviceWorker": true` inside the app configuration in .agular-cli.json. Building with the `--prod` flag will automatically add the service worker